# (Java) Using StringTokenizer to Read from textfile with Array

Tags: java, arrays, text-files, stringtokenizer

I'm trying to use StringTokenizer to read in data from a text file. The program I am writing is to read in various burger orders. The data I am trying to read in (toppings from burger order) is stored as a String array of size 7. It seems like everything is working fine except for when I am reading in more than one burger order from the text file and it looks like the last array of toppings replaces all the other arrays, meaning that I think my index is overriding the previous index. I tried to copy the array to an temporary array but it seems maybe I'm not doing it correctly. Any help will be appreciated.

```
while (infile.hasNextLine())
  {

     line = infile.nextLine();
     StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(value,", ");
     bun = tokens.nextToken();
     size = tokens.nextToken();


     line = infile.nextLine();
     tokens = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
     index = 0;
     while(tokens.hasMoreTokens())
     {
        burger_toppings[index] = tokens.nextToken();
        temporaryBurgerToppings= burger_toppings.clone();
        index++;

     }
  who = new Burger(size,bun,toppings);
  burger.add(who);
}
```

Comment: From [the documentation for `StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) "_`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code._" Don't use `StringTokenizer`.

Comment: I agree with you, but I  have to use StringTokenizer, even though I would prefer not to

Comment: Can please post the more detailed code. Looks like the part of the code you posted executing in a loop (maybe for multiple lines) and setting the index each time to 0.

Comment: @AmitBera I posted the full code to read in from file. It seems like the index is setting to 0 each time but how can I stop it from doing that since, the code is suppose to technically create two separate arrays each time it runs through. For example, Burger 1 has its own bun, size and toppings array. Burger 2 has its own bun, size and toppings and any other additional burgers will do the same.

Comment: @AmitBera I have tried that before and it gives me an error saying that ArrayIndexOutofBounds

Comment: Before implementing the business logic think about the design of the program. From your requirements, it looks like you are far behind to start writing the logic. So, please start designing the solution first. For example, your burger details (bun, size, and toppings) should be wrapped within a class and then you can maintain them in a list.

Comment: @AmitBera I have Burger within a class with all of the objects and methods. I am implementing the file read in and display in a test driver file.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue just create a new array for each Burger order(i.e declare the array again) at the beginning of the outer while loop.